# org-mode: day agenda: move scheduled task up and down

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to be able to schedule my task in Day agenda simply by moving a given task up and down on the day time line. Is it possible?

[image: [1]]

Comment: There is no built-in support for that feature, and writing it up with the ever changing / ongoing development of `org-mode` makes operating on a moving target rather difficult.  I would suggest submitting a feature request to the `org-mode` development team if someone doesn't write-up an answer within a reasonable period of time.  Absent a implementation of a new feature, you are probably limited to `org-agenda-schedule` and `org-agenda-deadline`.